# Turn specific row values into columns using R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, reshape2, melt

I have a dataset similar to the one listed below

```
v1 <-c('name1','0/0','0/1','1/1','name2','0/0','1/1','name3','0/0','0/1','1/1','name4','0/0','0/1','1/1','name5','0/0','1/1')
v2 <- c(NA,95,3,2,NA,98,2,NA,93,5,2,NA,94,3,3,NA,96,4)
df <- cbind(v1,v2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df
```

which looks like:

| v1 | v2 |
| --- | --- |
| name1 | NA |
| 0/0 | 95 |
| 0/1 | 3 |
| 1/1 | 2 |
| name2 | NA |
| 0/0 | 98 |
| 1/1 | 2 |
| name3 | NA |
| 0/0 | 93 |
| 0/1 | 5 |
| 1/1 | 2 |

How can I reshape the dataframe to look like:

| names | 0/0 | 0/1 | 1/1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 95 | 3 | 2 |
| name2 | 98 | NA | 2 |
| name3 | 93 | 5 | 2 |

Using reshape the closest I have gotten is:

| v1 | 0/0 | 0/1 | 1/1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 95 | . | . |
| 2 | . | 3 | . |
| 3 | . | . | 2 |
| 4 | 98 | . | . |
| 5 | . | . | 2 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use the `tidyverse` group of packages rather than `reshape2`, you can try this. The steps are

1. Create a new names column and fill it with any value from `v1` that contains the string "names"
2. `fill` the new `names` column, and `filter` out any rows which have an `NA` in the `v2` column
3. Use `tidyr::pivot_wider` to change to a wide format dataframe

```r
v1 <-c('name1','0/0','0/1','1/1','name2','0/0','1/1','name3','0/0','0/1','1/1','name4','0/0','0/1','1/1','name5','0/0','1/1')
v2 <- c(NA,95,3,2,NA,98,2,NA,93,5,2,NA,94,3,3,NA,96,4)
df <- cbind(v1,v2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(names = ifelse(str_detect(v1, 'name'), v1, NA)) %>%
  fill(names) %>%
  filter(!is.na(v2)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = v1,
              values_from = v2)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   names `0/0` `0/1` `1/1`
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 name1 95    3     2    
#> 2 name2 98    <NA>  2    
#> 3 name3 93    5     2    
#> 4 name4 94    3     3    
#> 5 name5 96    <NA>  4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How it works:

1. create a `id_Group`
2. `group_split` by `id_Group`
3. now you have a list of dataframes `my_list`
4. use `lapply` to `pivot_wider` all dataframes in your list
5. use `bind_rows` to combine the list of dataframes to one dataframe
6. to get the `name` column use `pivot_longer` with some subsequent tweaking:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- df %>% 
    mutate(id_Group = cumsum(is.na(v2))) %>% 
    group_split(id_Group) 

df_list <- lapply(1:length(my_list), 
                  function(x) (pivot_wider(my_list[[x]], names_from = v1, values_from = v2)))

bind_rows(df_list) %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = starts_with("name"),
        names_to = "name"
    ) %>% 
    group_by(id_Group) %>% 
    filter(row_number()==1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(name, contains("/"), -id_Group, -value)
```

```
  name  `0/0` `0/1` `1/1`
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 name1 95    3     2    
2 name1 98    NA    2    
3 name1 93    5     2    
4 name1 94    3     3    
5 name1 96    NA    4
```